# Cell lines are cut when using multiple rows

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, arrays, cell

Working in a large project with some commands defined for usage in a table. I list them below. Using them, I am trying to create a table which has multiple rows and still aligns the other cells correctly:

[image]

As can be seen I manage to get the multi-line, but not the correct cell lines and/or centering of the X's. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
% for loop - table 1
\usepackage{forloop}
\newcounter{loopcntr}
\newcommand{\rpt}[2][1]{%
  \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\on}[1][1]{
  \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{&\scriptsize X} 
}
\newcommand{\off}[1][1]{
  \forloop{loopcntr}{0}{\value{loopcntr}<#1}{&}
}

% extra table 1
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\centered}[1]{\begin{tabular}{l} #1 \end{tabular}}

% thick horizontal line (for table)
\makeatletter
\def\thickhline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height \thickarrayrulewidth \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xthickhline}
\def\@xthickhline{\ifx\reserved@a\thickhline
               \vskip\doublerulesep
               \vskip-\thickarrayrulewidth
             \fi
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\thickarrayrulewidth}
\setlength{\thickarrayrulewidth}{2\arrayrulewidth}



\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\begin{table}[h]
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\textwidth}
!{\vrule width 0.4mm}P{0.01\textwidth}*{1}{|P{0.01\textwidth}}
!{\vrule width 0.4mm}P{0.01\textwidth}*{3}{|P{0.01\textwidth}}
!{\vrule width 0.4mm}P{0.01\textwidth}*{3}{|P{0.01\textwidth}}
!{\vrule width 0.4mm}P{0.01\textwidth}*{1}{|P{0.01\textwidth}}
!{\vrule width 0.4mm}P{0.01\textwidth}*{1}{|P{0.01\textwidth}}
||}
\thickhline
\textbf{\vspace{-20pt}\diagbox[width=\dimexpr \textwidth/4+2\tabcolsep\relax, height=0.75cm]{ Package }{\centering Timeline }} 
           & \multicolumn{2}{c!{\vrule width 0.4mm}}{\scriptsize 2024} 
           & \multicolumn{4}{c!{\vrule width 0.4mm}}{\scriptsize 2025} 
           & \multicolumn{4}{c!{\vrule width 0.4mm}}{\scriptsize 2026} 
           & \multicolumn{2}{c!{\vrule width 0.4mm}}{\scriptsize 2027} 
           & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\vrule width 0.1mm}}{\scriptsize Involved people} \\
           
\cline{2-13}
\hspace{5.6cm} \scriptsize Quarters \rpt[1]{& \scriptsize 3 & \scriptsize 4} \rpt[2]{& \scriptsize 1 & \scriptsize 2 & \scriptsize 3 & \scriptsize 4} \rpt[1]{& \scriptsize 1 & \scriptsize 2} \rpt[1]{&} \\
\thickhline
\scriptsize Package1: \\ \scriptsize blabla      \on[4] \off[9] \scriptsize{Some Guy} \\[-10pt]
\hline
\scriptsize Package2: \\ \scriptsize more blabla \on[4] \off[9] \scriptsize{Some Other Guy} \\[-10pt]
\hline
\scriptsize Package3: \\ \scriptsize more blabla \off[2] \on[6] \off[5]  \\[-10pt]
\hline
\scriptsize Package4: \\ \scriptsize more blabla \off[6] \on[6] \off[1] \scriptsize{Some Guy} \\[-10pt]
\hline
\scriptsize Package5: \\ \scriptsize more blabla \on[4] \off[4] \on[4] \off[1] \\
\thickhline
\end{tabular}
\caption{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.}
\label{milestones}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\scriptsize` (like a row of other font-site related macros) works like a switch and takes no argument. Hence, `\scriptsize{Some Guy}` should really be just `\scriptsize Some Guy` (no braces needed, since the cell already creates a scope).

Comment: Please merge and complete your codes fragments to one MWE, which we can compile as it is and reproduce your problem.

Comment: I edited the code into one MWE. Should have done it before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of `tabularray` package and insert `x` where needed, the table's code can be significantly simplified:

```
\documentclass{report}%
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hline{4-Y}, 
             vline{1,4,6-8,10-12,14,Z}, 
             vline{3,5,9,13,15}=1pt,
             colsep  = 5pt,
             colspec = {X[l,m]  r *{2}{Q[c,m]} 
                                  *{4}{Q[c,m]} 
                                  *{4}{Q[c,m]}
                                  *{2}{Q[c,m]}
                        X[l,m]},
             cell{4-Z}{1} = {c=2}{},
             cell{4-Z}{2-Y} = {font=\sffamily},
             hspan = minimal,
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}}
    \toprule
    &   &   \SetCell[c=12]{c}   Timeline                
            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &                                                                        \\
    \cmidrule{3-14}
    & year:
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    2024
            &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    2025
                    &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    2026
                                    &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    2027
                                                    &   &\SetCell[r=2]{f}
                                                            Involved people
                                                                   \\
    \cmidrule{3-14}
packages
    & quoter:
        & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 &           \\
{Package 1:\\  \footnotesize   blabla}
    &   & x & x & x & x &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & Some Guy  \\
{Package 2:\\  \footnotesize     more blabla}
    &   & x & x & x & x &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & Some Guy  \\
{Package 3:\\  \footnotesize       more blabla}
    &   &   & x & x & x & x & x &   &   &   &   &   &   & Some Guy  \\
{Package 4:\\  \footnotesize      a brief summary of the tasks of this package}
    &   &   &   & x & x & x & x & x &   &   &   &   &   & Some Guy  \\
{Package 5:\\  \footnotesize       more blabla}
    &   & x & x & x & x &   &   &   &   & x & x & x & x & Some Guy  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.}
\label{milestones}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**Edit:** changed indstruction `cell{3-Z}{2-Y}` to `cell{4-Z}{2-Y}`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked flawlessly :) 
Using this package was not something I had in mind until now.

Comment: +1: Also, nice to change \ShowFrameLinethickness.